# How to access encrypted passwords from specific location using gradle-credentials-plugin

Tags: marklogic, gradle-plugin, ml-gradle

We are using gradle-credentials-plugin to encrypt project passwords

--Add credentials:

```
gradle addCredentials --key "InitialPassword" --value $pwdValue -PcredentialsLocation=${baseDir}
```

--Read Passwords:

```
project.IntialPassword = credentials.InitialPassword
```

> Error:  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
>
> Reason: Encrypted passwords file not finding as the plugin searching
>   in .gradle default folder

How to set `credentialsLocation` value so that the plugin can read password encrypted file from ${baseDir} in gradle.build?

tried setting credentialsLocation property but no luck.

Expected: The gradle credentials plugin must read encrypted passwords from custom directory.

Comment: This seems more specific to the gradle-credentials plugin as opposed to ml-gradle, but the instructions here may help - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Encrypting-passwords .

Comment: @rjrudin I tried referring the documentation but could not get any help. Also tried setting credentialsLocation but gradle still searching in default cache directory.    
  'setProperty("credentialsLocation",System.getProperty("user.dir"))'                                                           
                                                                                                                            
 If a custom directory location is passed through the credentialsLocation project property when starting the build, the credentials file will be seeked in that directory.

Comment: Have you verified that the user running gradle has permissions on the 'gradle.encrypted.properties'  file in the specified directory?

Comment: @Michael Yes I assume the user have permissions. Is there any specific way to check the user permissions?

Comment: @MichaelGardner ,the encrypted file gradle.encrypted.properties is created in the expected path -PcredentialsLocation=${baseDir} but when I tried to read the passwords from gradle.build it is still searching in gradle default home path.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the same custom location when storing the credentials as when reading the credentials.

https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-credentials-plugin#access-credentials-in-build

> If a custom directory location is passed through the
>   credentialsLocation project property when starting the build, the
>   credentials file will be seeked in that directory.

If you are not sure if the credentials got stored in the first place due to file permissions, then go to the location you specified and check the content of the `gradle.encrypted.properties` file. (though the task to store the credentials should have failed if there was a file permission issue)